# debug error heap corruption c++ pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, dynamic

so i have this assignment that tells the user to input two numbers and lets him choose some basic operations(like a calculator) from a menu. 
The goal of this exercise is to help us get more familiar with pointers/pointers to functions/dynamic allocation...The professor prefers that we use the "malloc" and "calloc" commands.

There is a part I'm stuck on, the part of displaying the history. It works for the first execution, but gives a debugging error as the code proceeds. Is there anyone who can help me solve the issue?

c++ code:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//structure for the history array
struct Operation{
float result;
int choice;
};


float add(float, float);
float sub(float, float);
float mult(float, float);
float divi(float, float);



int main(){
//size1=for 1st history array, size2=for 2nd history array, t=to check if an operation was done at least once
int choice,size1=0,t=0,i,size2=0;
//pointer to func
int(*operation)(int, int);

float  a, b,result;
//pointers set to NULL
Operation *history1 = NULL, *history1i = NULL, *history2 = NULL, *history2i = NULL;

cout << "Enter 2 numbers a & b: ";
cin >> a >> b;
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl << "1=Addition" << endl << "2=Subtraction" << endl << "3=Division" << endl;
cout << "4=Multiplication" << endl << "5=Display History" << endl << "6=Exit" << endl;

do{
    cin >> choice;
    //initialize the size of 1st array if a choice is valid
    if (choice < 5 && choice >0)
        size1++;
    //initialize 1st array
    history1 = (Operation*)calloc(size1, sizeof(Operation));
    if (history1 == NULL){
        cout << "History allocation failed."<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    //menu
    switch (choice){
    case 1: result = (add)(a, b);
        cout << endl << "The addition of " << a << " & " << b << " gives: " << result << endl;
        break;
    case 2:result = (sub)(a, b);
        cout << endl << "The subtraction of " << a << " & " << b << " gives: " << result << endl;
        break;
    case 3:if (b != 0){
                result = (divi)(a, b);
                cout << endl << "The division of " << a << " & " << b << " gives: " << result << endl;
            }
           else
               cout << "Can't perform the divison.";
        break;
    case 4:result = (mult)(a, b);
        cout << endl << "The multiplication of " << a << " & " << b << " gives: " << result << endl;
        break;
    //display history
    case 5:if (t == 1){
                cout << endl << "Your history is: " << endl;
                for (history2i = history2,i=1; (history2i - history2) < size2; history2i++,i++){
                    cout << "\t"<<i<<"-  " << a;

                    if (history2i->choice == 1)
                        cout << " + ";
                    else if (history2i->choice == 2)
                        cout << " - ";
                    else if (history2i->choice == 3)
                        cout << " / ";
                    else
                        cout << " * ";

                    cout << b << " = " << history2i->result<<endl;
                }
            }
           else
               cout <<endl<< "You haven't done any calcualtions yet."<<endl;
        break;
    case 6:break;
    default:cout << endl << "The option you entered is not valid." << endl;
        break;
    }
    //if choice is valid
    if (choice < 5 && choice >0){
        //if at least one opertion executed copy the elements of history2 in history1
        if (t == 1){
            for (history1i = history1, history2i = history2; (history1i - history1) < size2; history1i++, history2i++){
                history1i->result = history2i->result;
                history1i->choice = history2i->choice;
            }
            history1i++;//in order to enter the new operation
        }
        //if no operation done
        else{
            history1i = history1;
        }
        history1i->result = result;
        history1i->choice = choice;
    }
    //if at least one operation done=>history exists and not NULL
    if (t == 1){
        free(history2);//in order to create a new array with the new elements
        history2 = NULL;
    }
    //if not operations done before increment t
    if (choice < 5 && choice >0 && t == 0){
        t++;
    }
    //if valid choice create history 2
    if (choice < 5 && choice >0){
        size2 = size1;
        history2 = (Operation*)calloc(size2, sizeof(Operation));
        if (history2 == NULL){
            cout << "History allocation failed." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        //store all the previous history including the new one
        for (history2i = history2, history1i = history1; (history2i - history2) < size2; history2i++, history1i++){
            history2i->result = history1i->result;
            history2i->choice = history1i->choice;
        }
    }

    free(history1);
    history1 = NULL;

    if (choice != 6)
        cout << endl << "Choose another option: ";


} while (choice != 6);
return 0;
}

float add(float a, float b){
    return a + b;
}
float sub(float a, float b){
    return a - b;
}
float mult(float a, float b){
    return a*b;
}
float divi(float a, float b){
    return a / b;
}
```

Comment: _The professor prefers that we use the "malloc"_ why??

Comment: Are you forced to use C++98?

Comment: Please realize we have to read all your code and figure out where it has an issue...?  Do you have any idea where the problem lies?  Do you get any error, logic fault, ...?  Print debugging text in your code to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Oups, if you want to use arrays, you must allocate all the array in one single allocation call (you can use `realloc` to keep the initial part of the previous allocated array). And if you want to allocate one element on each pass, you must use a linked list where each element has a pointer to the next one (or to nullptr for the last element).

Comment: _The professor prefers that we use the "malloc" and "calloc" commands_ YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)